# Output Explanation of this program in C?

Tags: c, endianness

I have this program in C:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  int i=300;
  char *ptr = &i;
  *++ptr=2;
  printf("%d",i);
  return 0;
}
```

The output is 556 on little endian.

I tried to understand the output. Here is my explanation.

**Question is Will the answer remains the same in the big endian machine?**

i = 300;
=> i = 100101100 //in binary in word format => B B Hb 0001 00101100 where B = Byte and Hb = Half Byte

(A)=> in memory (assuming it is Little endian))

```
0x12345678 - 1100 - 0010 ( Is this correct for little endian)

0x12345679 - 0001 - 0000

0x1234567a - 0000 - 0000

0x1234567b - 0000 - 0000
```

0x1234567c - Location of next intezer(location of ptr++ or ptr + 1 where ptr is an intezer pointer as ptr is of type int => on doing ++ptr it will increment by 4 byte(**size of int**))

when

(B)we do char *ptr = &i; 
ptr will become of type char => on doing ++ptr it will increment by 1 byte(**size of char**)
so on doing ++ptr it will jump to location -> 0x12345679 (which has 0001 - 0000)
now we are doing 
*++ptr = 2
=> 0x12345679 will be overwritten by 2 => 0x12345679 will have 00**10** - 0000 instead of 000**1** - 0000

so the new memory content will look like this :

(C)

```
0x12345678 - 1100 - 0010

0x12345679 - 0010 - 0000

0x1234567a - 0000 - 0000

0x1234567b - 0000 - 0000
```

which is equivalent to => B B Hb 0010 00101100 where B = Byte and Hb = Half Byte

Is my reasoning correct?Is there any other short method for this?
Rgds,
Softy

Comment: [_void main_](http://users.aber.ac.uk/auj/voidmain.cgi)?

Comment: I believe this behaviour is not well-defined because the size of `int` is not guaranteed to be 4 bytes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a little-endian 32-bit system, the int `300` (`0x012c`) is typically(*) stored as 4 sequential bytes, lowest first:  `2C 01 00 00`.  When you increment the char pointer that was formerly the int pointer `&i`, you're pointing at the second byte of that sequence, and setting it to 2 makes the sequence `2C 02 00 00` -- which, when turned back into an int, is `0x22c` or 556.

(As for your understanding of the bit sequence...it seems a bit off.  Endianness affects *byte* order in memory, as the byte is the smallest addressable unit.  The bits within the byte don't get reversed; the low-order byte will be `2C` (`00101100`) whether the system is little-endian or big-endian.  (Even if the system did reverse the bits of a byte, it'd reverse them again to present them to you as a number, so you wouldn't notice a difference.)  The big difference is where that byte appears in the sequence.  The only places where *bit* order matters, is in hardware and drivers and such where you can receive less than a byte at a time.)

In a big-endian system, the int is typically(*) represented by the byte sequence `00 00 01 2C` (differing from the little-endian representation solely in the byte order -- highest byte comes first).  You're still modifying the second byte of the sequence, though...making `00 02 01 2C`, which as an int is `0x02012c` or 131372.

<sup><sup>(*)</sup> Lots of things come into play here, including two's complement (which almost all systems use these days...but C doesn't require it), the value of `sizeof(int)`, alignment/padding, and whether the system is truly big- or little-endian or a half-assed implementation of it.  This is a big part of why mucking around with the bytes of a bigger type so often leads to undefined or implementation-specific behavior.</sup>

Comment: "When you increment the char pointer that was formerly the int pointer `&i`, you're pointing at the second byte of that sequence[.]" Pointer arithmetic really is a tricky little thing if you aren't careful.

Answer (score 3):

This is your `int`:

```
int i = 300;
```

And this is what the memory contains at `&i`: `2c 01 00 00`
With the next instruction you assign the address of `i` to `ptr`, and then you move to the next byte with `++ptr` and change its value to `2`:

```
char *ptr = &i;
*++ptr = 2;
```

So now the memory contains: `2c 02 00 00` (i.e. 556).
The difference is that in a [*big-endian system*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) in the address of `i` you would have seen `00 00 01 2C`, and after the change: `00 02 01 2C`.

Even if the internal rappresentation of an `int` is *implementation-defined*:

> For signed integer types, the bits of the object representation shall
>   be divided into three groups: value bits, padding bits, and the sign
>   bit. There need not be any padding bits; signed char shall not have
>   any padding bits. There shall be exactly one sign bit. Each bit that
>   is a value bit shall have the same value as the same bit in the object
>   representation of the corresponding unsigned type (if there are M
>   value bits in the signed type and N in the unsigned type, then M ≤ N).
>   If the sign bit is zero, it shall not affect the resulting value. If
>   the sign bit is one, the value shall be modified in one of the
>   following ways: — the corresponding value with sign bit 0 is negated
>   (sign and magnitude); — the sign bit has the value −(2M) (two’s
>   complement); — the sign bit has the value −(2M − 1) (ones’
>   complement). Which of these applies is **implementation-defined**, as
>   is whether the value with sign bit 1 and all value bits zero (for the
>   first two), or with sign bit and all value bits 1 (for ones’
>   complement), is a trap representation or a normal value. In the case
>   of sign and magnitude and ones’ complement, if this representation is
>   a normal value it is called a negative zero.

Comment: The question is what happens with big endian though.

Answer (score 3):

This is implementation defined. The internal representation of an int is not known according to the standard, so what you're doing is not portable. See section 6.2.6.2 in the C standard.

However, as most implementations use two's complement representation of signed ints, the endianness will affect the result as described in cHaos answer.

Answer (score 1):

I like experiments and that's the reason for having the PowerPC G5.

stacktest.c:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i=300;
  char *ptr = &i;
  *++ptr=2;
  /* Added the Hex dump */
  printf("%d or %x\n",i, i);
  return 0;
}
```

Build command:

```
powerpc-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.2.1 -o stacktest stacktest.c
```

Output:

```
131372 or 2012c
```

Resume: the cHao's answer is complete and in case you're in doubt here is the experimental evidence.